# How to sum values of cell presented in different ways EXCEL?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 type of cells:

- just number
- numbers as a column (in a single cell)
- empty cells

Desired output is: 5 (sum of all numbers by taking into account empty cell as well)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For examle:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,A1:C1),CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

**Note1:** `TEXTJOIN` requires Excel 2019 or O365, but otherwise you could just concatenate the three cells using `CHAR(10)`.

**Note2:** `FILTERXML` requires Excel 2013 or higher.

---

For old versions maybe use:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(--A1),--A1,SUM(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A;LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))))
```

**Note:** It's an array formula and needs entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Drag the formula three cells to the right and add the three returned values in a seperate column (I used `G1`).

Comment: @MamedMamedov, see my edited answer with a recommendation?

Comment: let me check, I ll tell you